# Parralax jutter on UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've got several UITableView's with custom cells that I apply a parallax effect to. In my Tableview I call

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSArray *visibleCells = [self.tableView visibleCells];

    for (FeedTableViewCell *cell in visibleCells) {
        [cell cellOnTableView:self.tableView didScrollOnView:self.view];
    }
}
```

In my custom cell, the method looks like this:

```
- (void)cellOnTableView:(UITableView *)tableView didScrollOnView:(UIView *)view {
CGRect rectInSuperview = [tableView convertRect:self.frame toView:view];

float distanceFromCenter = CGRectGetHeight(view.frame)/2 - CGRectGetMinY(rectInSuperview);
float difference = CGRectGetHeight(self.image.frame) - CGRectGetHeight(self.frame);
float move = (distanceFromCenter / CGRectGetHeight(view.frame)) * difference;

CGRect imageRect = self.image.frame;
imageRect.origin.y = -(difference/2)+move;
self.image.frame = imageRect;
}
```

When I first load the tableview and scroll there is a noticeable 'jump' as the image updates, but then after this initial set the effect is smooth as can be. I'm trying to figure out how to get rid of that jump. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you loading images from disc? How big are they? My guess is that you're loading large images on the main thread (resulting in the lag, since UI updates happen on the main thread).

Comment: You can choose https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage or AsyncImageView for  better user experience

Comment: Using SDWebImage, and using it to cache them images. Even when they are cached the jutter still happens. It doesn't appear to be related to the loading of the images, something about the parallax

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the image's frame for parallax on load else when you start scroller there's a jump as the images change from their default from to their parallax from. To do this you can add.

Add:

```
[cell cellOnTableView:tableView didScrollOnView:self.view];
```

to your implementation of:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

If you're using auto layout for your tableview's from, you likely also need:

```
[self.tableview reloadData];
```

to viewDidAppear

Comment: Sorry, should have said that I already tried that with no luck

Comment: You're not telling us everything then. Because I've copied your code and it works fine for me.

Comment: Thought maybe I was missing the viewDidLayoutSubviews aspect, but even that didn't fix it

Comment: Try it in viewDidAppear

Comment: Afraid I'm still getting a jump. Could it have something to do with the fact that the images I'm getting from the web are all different sizes? I have the image set to AspectFit in IB

Comment: Neither of those things have anything to do with it. You've not described the jump you're seeing. Regardless, if you don't include the code above, you'll obviously have a jump because cell.image's frame is going to not be adjusted to match the layout of the parallax frame and there's going to be a jump, particularly among rows at the top and bottom of the screen as they have to travel far to catch up with the parallax frame. You can try just including [cell cellOnTableView:tableView didScrollOnView:self.view]; in cellForRowAtIndexPath and turning off the constraints for you tableView.